With new Google Policy for releasing an app on Google Play, do testers need to provide feedback?
I'm releasing an app on Google Play and I don't understand do testers need to provide feedback? Because our colleagues already tested our app and we fixed all the bugs that were found. Or do they just need to use it every day
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/14151465?hl=en#zippy=%2Csummary-of-testing-requirements-per-track%2Cpart-tell-us-about-your-closed-test%2Cpart-tell-us-about-your-appgame  I read this and I still don't understand
